# Limit RDP by HostName (not IP)

Tags: security, rdp, remote-access

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server with RDP access enabled. However I'm not limited access by IP.

*Why..*

I'm a 2 person company so all server issues I have to care of.

Last weekend I was out hiking and I got call from a client that their site was down.
Using an iPhone (with the RDP client app) I was able to connect to the server recycle the IIS app pool and save the day from all from the top of a mountain.

However this is not very secure. I need to limit RDP access by IP address.
However the iPhone does not have a static address, it changes all the time. The only thing *static* about it is that the host name always contains ".mycingular.net"

Is there anyway I can limit RDP access by hostnames (with wildcards, e.g." *.mycingular.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is no, there is no way to do this using what is built-in to windows.  You could setup a VPN between the iPhone and your network.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1424

Comment: perfect! http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1424